# Downloading files from a site to a specific folder with a specific extension

Tags: html, css, json, file, sites

I want to implement this idea. I have a **folder** on my PC with the following structure:
There is a Site folder and in it:

1. index.html
2. style.css
3. **new folder**

index.html is my site page, and I want to make a file upload button of a certain type on this page. that is, the usual, standard form of uploading files, but only for a certain type of files.
And when a user uploads a file to my page, this file is placed in the **New folder**. How can I implement this? What should be used for this? Maybe there are articles that I missed on the Internet, although I climbed many sites. Tell me what can be done?

Comment: Where is the user? I assume not sitting at your PC? How are you going to serve the page? Is your PC set up as the server? We need to know the context and it will be the server side that needs to do some image checking/saving.

Comment: no, all the listed files are on my PC, I have only one index .html page, I want to understand and work out the mechanism for uploading files to the site, I will upload the files now and no one else. I want to understand how to do it and what to do.